# как запустить этот код? python

Tags: python, ооп

```
class Soldat():
    def __init__(self,name,age,gender,height,weight):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.gender=gender
        self.height=height
        self.weight=weight
    def prints(self):
        print("""
            {}-soldier name
            {}-soldier age
            {}-soldier gender
            {}-soldier height
            {}-soldier weight
        """.format(self.name,self.age,self.gender,self.height,self.weight))

class Armiya(Soldat):
    def soldier(self):
        s1=("Ali",19,"erkak",155,75)
        s2=("qiz bola",17,"Ayol",140,55)
        s3=("Alisher",20,"erkak",160,65)
        if s1.age>18 and s1.gender=="erkak" and s1.height>150 and s1.weight>75:
            print("{}-Yo'nalish:Piyoda askar".format(s1.name))
        else:
            print("{}-Yo'nalish:Tank askar".format(s1.name))
        if s2.age>18 and s2.gender=="erkak" and s2.height>150 and s2.weight>75:
            print("{}-Yo'nalish:Piyoda askar".format(s2.name))
        else:
            print("{}-Yo'nalish:Tank askar".format(s2.name))
        if s3.age>18 and s3.gender=="erkak" and s3.height>150 and s3.weight>75:
            print("{}-Yo'nalish:Piyoda askar".format(s3.name))
        else:
            print("{}-Yo'nalish:Tank askar".format(s3.name))
```

Comment: Этот код не является исполняемым, а точнее это обрывок какого-то кода. Запустить можно только исходный код, а не этот обрывок.

Comment: есть подозрение что s1 s2 s3 у вас не в том месте стоят

Comment: Тут `s1=("Ali",19,"erkak",155,75)` нет вызова объекта `Soldat`: ``s1=Soldat("Ali",19,"erkak",155,75)``, аналогично для `s2` и `s3`

Answer (score 1):

Вот "рабочий" вариант остальное в комментариях в коде.:

```py
class Soldat():
    def __init__(self,name,age,gender,height,weight):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.gender=gender
        self.height=height
        self.weight=weight
    def prints(self):
        print("""
            {}-soldier name
            {}-soldier age
            {}-soldier gender
            {}-soldier height
            {}-soldier weight
        """.format(self.name,self.age,self.gender,self.height,self.weight))

class Armiya(Soldat):
    def soldier(self):
        # s1=("Ali",19,"erkak",155,75) # это кортеж с которым Вы не работаете далее в коде.
        s1=Soldat("Ali",19,"erkak",155,75) # а это экземпляр класса soldat которые ожидается далее в коде.
        s2=Soldat("qiz bola",17,"Ayol",140,55)
        s3=Soldat("Alisher",20,"erkak",160,65)
        if s1.age>18 and s1.gender=="erkak" and s1.height>150 and s1.weight>75:
            print("{}-Yo'nalish:Piyoda askar".format(s1.name))
        else:
            print("{}-Yo'nalish:Tank askar".format(s1.name))
        if s2.age>18 and s2.gender=="erkak" and s2.height>150 and s2.weight>75:
            print("{}-Yo'nalish:Piyoda askar".format(s2.name))
        else:
            print("{}-Yo'nalish:Tank askar".format(s2.name))
        if s3.age>18 and s3.gender=="erkak" and s3.height>150 and s3.weight>75:
            print("{}-Yo'nalish:Piyoda askar".format(s3.name))
        else:
            print("{}-Yo'nalish:Tank askar".format(s3.name))        


s = Soldat("name", 18, "male", 10, 20) # Создает экземпляр с заданными параметрами.. 
s.prints() # Используем метод (просто печатаем инфо)
print("------------------")
a = Armiya("name", 18, "male", 10, 20) # Зачем передаем не используемые в последствии параметры?
a.soldier() # Вызов метода...
```

Переписанный класс:

```py
class Armiya():
    def add(self, Sold):
        for i in Sold:
            self.soldier(i)

    def soldier(self, soldat):
        if soldat.age > 18 and soldat.gender == "erkak" and soldat.height > 150 and soldat.weight > 75:
            print("{}-Yo'nalish:Piyoda askar".format(soldat.name))
        else:
            print("{}-Yo'nalish:Tank askar".format(soldat.name))

# Создаем список солдат... 
s_list=[]
s_list.append(Soldat("Ali",19,"erkak",155,80))
s_list.append(Soldat("qiz bola",17,"Ayol",140,55))
s_list.append(Soldat("Alisher",20,"erkak",160,65))

a = Armiya()
a.add(s_list) # для списка солдат
a.soldier(Soldat("Alisher_new",20,"erkak",160,65)) # для одного солдата
```

Comment: Еще я бы убрал наследование армии от солдат

Comment: @insolor по хорошему да... оно там ни к чему да и не нужно будет передавать лишние параметры, плюс в `soldier` бесполезные повторения. По уму имхо тут лучше вообще переписать класс.  Дополнил в ответ.